# mapping NUMBER(15) in hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

So we have in our data schema column of type `NUMBER(15)`. How to map it in hibernate without changing schema? `int` data type is too small for that, `long` data type is too big for that(ORA-01438), even when persisting numbers withing DB column bounds.

Assume, that schema is unmodifiable and we do not want to use BigInteger. Say, that we know, that number wont be bigger than 372036854775807, thus can fit into both long and NUMBER(15).

Oracle DB.

Comment: Well `BigInteger` might be what you should be using on the Java side, since it is large enough and also is an exact numeric type.

Comment: Also, please tell us which database you are using.

Comment: It's ORACLE db, and assumption asks not to use BigInteger. We're not ok with performance loss related to BigInteger.

Comment: Either you use `DOUBLE PRECISION`, bit the bullet, and give up a little extra storage space, or you use `BigDecimal`.  These are your only options, AFAIK.

Comment: that's what 'm afraid of; I never saw any mapping allowing to 'fix' that. But not having this option is little bit limiting for legacy systems ...

Comment: Imho the right type is BigDecimal. You usually do not use there "numbers" for any math operation anyway. And Oracle stores NUMBERs in decimal format too. So with BigDecimal you hame one-to-one mapping between the app and db. With any risk of loosing any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so actually this was my fault, due to misread of oracle documentation, regarding number scale and precision. I thought, that precision is the part before '.', and scale after it, but no, precision is number of all digits. That was causing my problem, and on different column.

To answer my own question: ORA-01438 won't be thrown for numbers which fit into type used in DB layer. Therefore if I know, that data type used on app layer cannot be bigger than number(15), I can safely use long in java and NUMBER(15) in DB. Until this constraint is violated, everything is fine. And adhering to this constraint is important in first place, and BigInteger won't help without it, since BigInteger can be bigger than NUMBER(37).